# Foundation 5 menu-bar toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, zurb-foundation

I have been trying everything to fix this. Yet something seems to be wrong somewhere. I tried adding `foundation.topbar.js` and `foundation.min.js` is also added. There are no JS errors anywhere in the site. Just not able to understand what is causing this bug. Here is my code,

*navbar.handlebars*

```
<nav class="top-bar top_bar_custom" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <a href="#">
                {{#brandLogo}}
                    <img src="{{imgSrc}}" alt="">
                {{/brandLogo}}
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Menu</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul>
            {{#navItems}}
            <li class="top_bar_li">
                <a href="">{{anchorData}}</a>
            </li>
            {{/navItems}}
        </ul>
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="has-dropdown top_bar_li not-click">
                {{#profileArea}}
                <a href="#">{{anchorData}} <span>{{username}}</span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    {{#dropdown}}
                    <li>
                        <a class="ddHeight" href="#">{{firstLink}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a class="ddHeight" href="#">{{secondLink}}</a>
                    </li>
                    {{/dropdown}}
                </ul>
                {{/profileArea}}
            </li>
            <li class="top_bar_li pic_middle">
                <img src="images/profile_pic.png" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

*the way it is linked in html*

```
    </footer>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script src="js/raty/jquery.raty.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chartist/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebars-v2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/templates/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="js/all.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
```

*This is the part where I call the handlebar templates in all.js file*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // below written code is used for adapting single sidebar and navbar throught the site
    //using jQuery getjson method
    $.getJSON("sidebar.json", function(data) {
        // code for navbar here
        var navbar = $('#navbar');
        var navTag = $('<nav class="top-bar top_bar_custom" data-topbar role="navigation"></nav>');
        navbar.append(navTag);
        // var navbar = $("#navbar-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.templates['navbar'];
        $('#navBar').append(template(data));

        var template = Handlebars.templates['sidebar'];
        $('#sidebar').append(template(data));

    });
```

.
  .
  rest of the code..

Comment: The menu-bar is the foundation nav-bar ? And what does it mean "toggle not working" ?

Comment: Yes it is nav-bar. When we resize the screen and it reaches mobile resolution we get a menu which toggles on click. That clicking is not happening here. Since I am loading the navbar using AJAX from a JSON file. I think there is some issue with event delegation. Any idea?

Comment: Okay, I think you have to reinitialize foundation after to have loaded the nav-bar, with someting like that `$(document).foundation('topbar')`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still no luck.

Comment: And if you don't use AJAX, is it all right ?

Comment: I think I have confused you. I am fetching handlebar templates using `getJSON` library. Yes it works without handlebar's template. I think the loading of the template has messed something up. I have updated the code. There's a lot going on and please forgive me if I am not making myself clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65680/discussion-between-general03-and-thomas-sebastian).